# Does the formula for arc length hold for other coordinate systems?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

Does the formula for arc length, integration of $\sqrt{(x'(t))^2 + (y'(t))^2 + (z'(t))^2}$, hold for other coordinate systems, such as cylindrical coordinates, meaning can I compute the integral of  $\sqrt{(r'(t))^2 + (\theta'(t))^2 + (z'(t))^2}$ to get the arc length of a curve in 3-D that is parametrized in cylindrical coordinates?  Or, do I have to first convert r(t), $\theta(t)$ and z(t) to x(t), y(t), z(t) coordinates, before applying the formula?

Edit: Converting to x,y,z worked for me in an arc length problem.  However, *keeping* the cylindrical coordinates and going for the integration of $\sqrt{(r'(t))^2 + (\theta'(t))^2 + (z'(t))^2}$ doesn't seem to work.

Is it just simply because the arc length formula is derived by the Pythagoras theorem and so must require rectangular coordinates to make sense?

Comment: No, they do not. There are dedicated formulas for arc length in other coordinates (and one can always rewrite in rectangular coordinates).

Comment: Ah, no wonder!  Painful calculations today in a completely wrong direction, but at least now I won't forget this!  Thanks so much, @Travis :-)

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help. Someone may well have already asked about it (I suggest searching), but if not, it would be worthwhile to ask for the arc length formula in cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: Your last paragraph is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Ok, got it - thanks, @AlexM!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cylindrical coordinates, i.e. $(r,\theta,z)$ with $x=r\cos\theta,y=r\sin\theta$ we have
$$
x'(t)=r'(t)\cos\theta(t)-r(t)\theta'(t)\sin\theta(t),\quad y'(t)=r'(t)\sin\theta(t)+r(t)\theta'(t)\cos\theta(t).
$$
Therefore
$$
(x'(t))^2+(y'(t))^2=[(r'(t))^2+r^2(t)(\theta'(t))^2]\cdot[\cos^2\theta(t)+\sin^2\theta(t)]=(r'(t))^2+r^2(t)(\theta'(t))^2,
$$
and the formula to compute the arc length in cylindrical coordinates is:
$$
\int_a^b\sqrt{(r'(t))^2+r^2(t)(\theta'(t))^2+(z'(t))^2}\,dt,
$$
assuming that the curve is defined on $[a,b]$.